# Why use Decimal.Multiply vs operator multiply?

Tags: c#, math

```
decimal result = 100 * 200;
```

**vs**

```
decimal result = Decimal.Multiply(100, 200);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using the `Decimal.Multiply` will force the multiply to take inputs of type `decimal` instead of whatever the type that is being used and converted to `decimal`.

`Decimal.Multiply(decimal d1, decimal d2)` and will enforce and output of type `decimal`.  Where as the `*` you could do:

```
decimal result = yourDecimal * yourInt;
```

This allows you to mix and match types in some cases and it will handle it all for you but the type is not guaranteed to be decimal depending on how the right side is defined.

Comment: Good point.  So more than just a readability issue as Chris pointed out, also a type-safe way of using multiply.  Nice!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  The `int` value is implicitly converted to `decimal` before the multiplication takes place so you're doing decimal arithmetic in any case.  If you were multiplying two `int` values then assigning to decimal that might be an issue, but you can get around that by casting one to decimal first without having to use the `Multiply` method.

Comment: I guess you meant it correctly but your example seems to suggest you are _not allowed_ to do `Decimal.Multiply(yourDecimal, yourInt)`, which you, of course, are – there is an implicit conversion from int to decimal. Only with Decimal.Multiply, you can be sure _decimal_ multiplication is used, which can be important e.g. `int i1 = 1000000; decimal x = i1 * i1;` versus `decimal x = Decimal.Multiply(i1, i1);`

Comment: @Mormegil yes I ment everything will for sure happen as `decimal` and the output is guaranteed to be `decimal`. To me it is just more obvious but the same conversion will be happening. In some case (not decimal) you could probably switch the result type and the * would still work where the `Multiply` would no longer compile.

Answer (score 11):

The `*` operator is overloaded and calls `Multiply` internally. It's really just a matter of readability.

Comment: Have you considered what happens with `decimal result = int.MaxValue * 2;`?

Comment: @mgronber - that's not a reason to use `Multiply`, that's a reason to understand integer overflow, using the correct type for the operation, and typecasting/promotion. The correct thing to do if you find someone resorting to calling `Multiply` in such a case is to sit them down and have a discussion about numeric representations and choosing (casting to) the right type.  Strictly speaking, the way this question is worded, this isn't really an answer either -- at least to me since `100 * 200` is much more readable, though I'd write it `100m * 200m` to be consistent with the types.

Comment: Ah yes, well I suppose in that case the RHS will be evaluated as an integer (which will overflow), whereas the Decimal.Multiply solution will NOT overflow. So the correct way to call this with the `*` operator is `(decimal)int.MaxValue * (decimal)2`.

Comment: @Chris - or just `int.MaxValue * 2m`

Comment: @tvanfosson: Yes, I agree about the use of `Multiply`. However, the example uses two ints so the question is not just a matter of readability. One must understand that the correct operator overload is only used if at least one of the types is decimal.

Comment: @mgronber - yes, but you **have** to understand how arithmetic is being done given the types of operands.  Suggesting to use `Multiply` as an alternative to understanding about how conversion/promotion works is to leave someone in ignorance.  You end up with people doing decimal multiplication and assigning back to an int *"just to be safe."*

Comment: @tvanfosson: Have I suggested that the `Multiply` would be better alternative? I have tried to state that the correct operator overload requires that at least one of the types is decimal. Otherwise it is not the same as `Decimal.Multiply`.

Comment: @mgronber - I was interpreting your comment in the context of the question of why to use `Multiply` over the multiplication operator.  Sorry if that's not what you intended.

Answer (score 9):

The `*` operator is overloaded for decimal types and it is identical to `Decimal.Multiply()`. However, the overloaded `*` operator requires that at least one of the parameters is decimal. Otherwise, some other `*` operator is called. In `decimal result = 100 * 200` the int types are first multiplied and then converted to decimal. If the multiplication result is bigger than `Int32.MaxValue`, you will get an overflow.

```
decimal d1 = 2147483647 * 2; // Overflow
decimal d2 = 2147483647m * 2; // OK
decimal d3 = Decimal.Multiply(2147483647, 2); // OK
```

Answer (score 4):

Some languages do not support overloaded operators; those must call the Multiply() method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement for a .NET language to directly support decimals, but in such a language you can still use the System.Decimal struct. Since there's also no requirement that a .NET language support operator overrides, the methods are needed to allow for full use in such a case.

Comment: @Eric, Is Managed C++ not CLS compliant, or am I mis-remembering in thinking it has no direct support for decimal. Or is it the case that it is compliant through the operator overloads and a language without operator overloading would still have to support the operators on decimal?

Comment: That's a good question. I am not a lawyer of the CLS spec -- which is rather vague, as specs go -- and I am not an expert on C++/CLI by any means, so I'm not going to hazard a guess.